# Spring Data JPA do not set fields when fetch eagerly through ManyToOne

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'm new for Spring Data JPA and I'm working on two entities, User and Role, with ManyToOne relationship. The custom JpaRepository could fetch the Role when execute the query for User, but none fields of Role is set except the @Id of the Role even though the select statement includes a join select.
What should I do to make sure that the test case can be passed?

The issue:

> ```
> java.lang.AssertionError: 
> Expecting
>   <com.lenovo.dcg.epic.server.user.Role@36511c97>
> to have a property or a field named <"displayName"> with value
>   <"Administrator">
> but value was:
>   <null>
> ```

and the logs:

```
2018-09-11 23:22:10.885  INFO 56280 --- [    Test worker] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: 
    /* select
        generatedAlias0 
    from
        User as generatedAlias0 
    where
        generatedAlias0.username=:param0 */ select
            user0_.userID as userID1_2_0_,
            role1_.roleTypeID as roleType1_1_1_,
            user0_.createdBy as createdB2_2_0_,
            user0_.createdDate as createdD3_2_0_,
            user0_.email as email4_2_0_,
            user0_.firstName as firstNam5_2_0_,
            user0_.lastMaintainedBy as lastMain6_2_0_,
            user0_.lastMaintainedDate as lastMain7_2_0_,
            user0_.lastName as lastName8_2_0_,
            user0_.RoleTypeID as RoleTyp11_2_0_,
            user0_.title as title9_2_0_,
            user0_.username as usernam10_2_0_,
            role1_.createdBy as createdB2_1_1_,
            role1_.createdDate as createdD3_1_1_,
            role1_.displayName as displayN4_1_1_,
            role1_.lastMaintainedBy as lastMain5_1_1_,
            role1_.lastMaintainedDate as lastMain6_1_1_,
            role1_.roleTypeDesc as roleType7_1_1_ 
        from
            users user0_ 
        left outer join
            role_types role1_ 
                on user0_.RoleTypeID=role1_.roleTypeID 
        where
            user0_.username=?
2018-09-11 23:22:11.054 TRACE 56280 --- [    Test worker] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [xxx]
```

Here is my User entity.

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "User.detail", includeAllAttributes = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer userID;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    String username;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String firstName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String lastName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String email;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RoleTypeID", nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty(value = "RoleTypeID")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = UserRoleComponent.UserRoleDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = UserRoleComponent.UserRoleSerializer.class)
    Role role;
    String title;
    @JsonIgnore
    @CreationTimestamp
    Timestamp createdDate;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String createdBy;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String lastMaintainedBy;
    @JsonIgnore
    @UpdateTimestamp
    Timestamp lastMaintainedDate;
}
```

and here is my Role entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role_types")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer roleTypeID;
    String roleTypeDesc;
    String displayName;
    @CreationTimestamp
    Timestamp createdDate;
    String createdBy;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    Timestamp lastMaintainedDate;
    String lastMaintainedBy;
}
```

My Repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    @EntityGraph(value = "User.detail", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

and my test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest(properties = {"spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true",
        "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true",
        "logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE"})
public class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    private User user;


    private void initRoleType() throws ParseException {
        Role admin = new Role();
        admin.setRoleTypeDesc("Administrator");
        admin.setDisplayName("Administrator");
        admin.setCreatedBy("xxx");
        admin.setLastMaintainedBy("xxx");
        admin = entityManager.persist(admin);
        Role manager = new Role();
        manager.setRoleTypeDesc("Manager");
        manager.setDisplayName("Manager");
        manager.setCreatedBy("xxx");
        manager.setLastMaintainedBy("xxx");
        manager = entityManager.persist(manager);
        Role user = new Role();
        user.setRoleTypeDesc("User");
        user.setDisplayName("User");
        user.setCreatedBy("xxx");
        user.setLastMaintainedBy("xxx");
        user = entityManager.persist(user);
        entityManager.flush();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        resetIdentity();
        initRoleType();
        user = new User();
        user.setUsername("xxx");
        user.setFirstName("xxx");
        user.setLastName("xxx");
        user.setEmail("xxx@xxx.com");
        Role admin = new Role();
        admin.setRoleTypeID(1);
        user.setRole(admin);
        user.setTitle("Developer");
        user.setCreatedBy("admin");
        user.setLastMaintainedBy("admin");
    }

    private void resetIdentity() {
        EntityManager em = entityManager.getEntityManager();

        Query query = null;
        query = em
                .createNativeQuery("ALTER TABLE role_types ALTER COLUMN roleTypeID RESTART WITH 1");
        query.executeUpdate();
    }


    @Test
    public void testFindUserByName() {
        repository.save(user);
        entityManager.flush();
        Optional<User> user = repository.findByUsername("xxx");
        assertThat(user).isNotEmpty();
        assertThat(user).hasValueSatisfying(u -> {
            assertThat(u).hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("userID", 1);
            assertThat(u.getRole()).isNotNull();
            assertThat(u.getRole()).hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("roleTypeID", 1);
            assertThat(u.getRole()).hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("displayName", "Administrator");
            assertThat(u.getDisplayName()).isEqualTo("Administrator");
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I found out that this just caused by I used DataJpaTest but not SpringBootTest, but why?

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you have used? @DataJpaTest has no "properties", User has no "getDisplayName()".

Comment: Yes, the "properties" is new field since 2.1.0, and it can be visited [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.M2/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html). The getDisplayName() is my custom method just delegate the same method from role.
And I found the root cause is that the \@DataJpaTest includes \@ImportAutoConfiguration but \@SpringBootTest does not. But I don't why.

Comment: @koe I'm sorry for a copy&paste mistake, not \@ImportAutoConfiguration but \@Transactional